# Spark Structured Streaming OutOfMemoryError caused by thousands of KafkaMbean instances

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Spark Structured Streaming executor fails with OutOfMemoryError

Checking the heap allocation with VirtualVM indicate that JMX Mbean Server memory usage grows linearly with time.

After a further investigation it seems that JMX Mbean is filled with thousands of instances of KafkaMbean objects with metrics for consumer-(\d+) that goes into thousands (equal to the number of tasks created on the executor).

Running Kafka consumer with DEBUG logs on the executor shows that the executor adds thousands of metrics sensors and often does not remove them at all or only removes some

I am running HDP Spark 2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292 with HDP Kafka 1.0.0.2.6.5.0-292.

Here is how I initialise structured streaming:

```
sparkSession
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .options(Map("kafka.bootstrap.servers" -> KAFKA_BROKERS,
               "subscribePattern"        -> INPUT_TOPIC,
               "startingOffsets"         -> "earliest",
               "failOnDataLoss"          -> "false"))
  .mapPartitions(processData)
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .options(Map("kafka.bootstrap.servers" -> KAFKA_BROKERS,
               "checkpointLocation" -> CHECKPOINT_LOCATION))
  .queryName("Process Data")
  .outputMode("update")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1000))
  .load()
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

I was expecting Spark/Kafka to properly clean the MBeans on task completion, but that seems not to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your HDP version is probably using spark 2.3.1 which has a known bug reading data from Kafka(this issue appears when you are reading from a topic that doesn't have new data every micro batch):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24987

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25106

This bug was as a result of a change that was made in version 2.3.1 (it doesn't exists in version 2.3.0) so you can either upgrade your spark version or get a patch for your HDP version.